# Evaluating a double integral with tricky limits.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int^2_0 \int^0_{-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}xy^2\,dx\,dy = -0.8$$

I have evaluate this by changing to polar coordinates.

I have sketched it and decided that

$$\int^0_{-1} \int^{3\pi/2}_{\pi/2} r^4 \cos\theta \sin^2\theta \, d\theta \, dr = -2/15$$

but as you can see my answer differs from what is needed.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the "polar coordinate" you used is really centered at $(0,1)$, that is 
$$(x, y) = (r\cos\theta, 1+ r\sin\theta),$$
so the integrand should be 
$$r^2\cos\theta (1 +r\sin\theta)^2 $$
and from there you can check that the answer is $-0.8$.

Answer (score 1):

You even did not need to use polar coordinates $$\int xy^2\,dx=\frac{x^2 y^2}{2}$$ $$\int^0_{-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}xy^2\,dx=\frac{y^4}{2}-y^3$$ $$\int\left(\frac{y^4}{2}-y^3\right)\,dy=\frac{y^5}{10}-\frac{y^4}{4}$$ $$\int_0^2\left(\frac{y^4}{2}-y^3\right)\,dy=-\frac{4}{5}$$

Comment: I know. But It was part of the question. I found it easier to evaluate it as it was.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE. In the house of mathematics, there are many rooms. I hate polar coordinates (joke) !! Cheers.

Comment: I am the same, but specifically with spherical coordinates. THE DEVIL.